# Android - Parsing XML into an ArrayList

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm having trouble parsing and showing information from a very simple xml file.

First of all, I'm storing the xml file in the res/xml folder. In the folder I have an xml file named jokes.xml, the content of the file is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <joke>This is a good joke.</joke>
  <joke>This is a very nice good great joke.</joke>
  <joke>Oh Yeah!</joke>
</resources>
```

I want to parse this file, store all the jokes into an arraylist and the get a random one to show. My code is the following:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private TextView texto;
private int i = 0;
private String[] arrayJokes;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

    XmlResourceParser joke = getResources().getXml(R.xml.jokes);

    try {
        while( joke.getEventType() != XmlResourceParser.END_DOCUMENT ){
            if( joke.getEventType() == XmlResourceParser.START_TAG ){
                String s = joke.getName();

                if( s.equals("joke")){
                    arrayJokes[i] = joke.getAttributeValue(null, "joke");
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //takes random id from the array
    Random generator = new Random();
    int rnd = generator.nextInt(arrayJokes.length);

    String j = arrayJokes[rnd];
    texto.setText(j);

}

}
```

The problem is that I only get a blank page. Any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Cláudio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can parse your joke items like this:

```
private ArrayList<String> parseJokes() {
            ArrayList<String> jokes = new ArrayList<String>();
            XmlResourceParser parser = getResources().getXml(R.xml.jokes);


            try {
                int eventType=parser.getEventType();
                while (eventType!=XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
                    if(eventType==XmlPullParser.START_TAG){
                        if (parser.getName().equals("joke")) {
                            jokes.add(parser.nextText());
                        }
                    }

                    eventType= parser.next();
                }
            } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
                Log.e("XmlPullParserException", e.toString());
            }
            parser.close();
            return jokes;
        }
```

the main idea is to advance the parser across the document using the **next()** method.