# Parsing xml data with child nodes to arraylist

Tags: java, android, xml, arraylist

Given an xml file like this one, how would I go about parsing this data into an arraylist?

```
<Providers>
  <CarDealer name="BEFORWARD" id="1">
    <CarMake name="Toyota" id="20" stype="se01">
      <CarModel name="Belta" id="21"/>
      <CarModel name="RunX" id="22"/>
      <CarModel name="Corolla" id="23"/>
    </CarMake>
    <CarMake name="Nissan" id="30" stype="se02">
      <CarModel name="Murano" id="31"/>
      <CarModel name="Pathfinder" id="32"/>
      <CarModel name="Navara" id="33"/>
    </CarMake>
  </CarDealer>
```

Parsed data should be stored like this in arraylist:

```
(stype, id, CarMake_name, id, CarModel_name, id, CarModel_name, id, CarModel_name)
(stype, id, CarMake_name, id, CarModel_name, id, CarModel_name, id, CarModel_name)
```

Using SAXParser, this is what I tried to do but my arraylist is not showing anything when I print it out. Any help and tips will be appreciated; am a newbie to Android development:

```
public class SAXXMLHandler extends DefaultHandler {
private static List<Service> services = new ArrayList<Service>();
private Service serv = null;
public String text = null;

public List<Service> getService() {

    return services;
}

@Override
// A start tag is encountered.
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes)
    throws SAXException {
    switch (qName) {
        // Create a new Service.
        case "CarMake": {
            serv = new Service();
            serv.setID(Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("id")));
            serv.setName(attributes.getValue("name"));
            serv.setStype(attributes.getValue("stype"));
            break;
        }
    }
}

public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
    switch (qName) {
        case "CarMake": {
            // The end tag of an service was encountered, so add the service to the list.
            services.add(serv);
            break;
        }
        case "CarModel": {
            serv.setName(attributes.getValue("name"));
            serv.setID(Integer.parseInt(attributes.getValue("id")));

            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android - Parsing XML into an ArrayList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26225041/android-parsing-xml-into-an-arraylist)

Comment: @minasameh umhm not really. I feel it is slightly different from mine because I have two objects for `CarMake` that contain child nodes `CarModel`. Iterating through them and adding the nodes to the arraylist is my challenge. But thanks for the link; have gotten something from it.